# A moment-based stochastic order

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions, moments

Given that a Borel probability measure $\mu$ on [0,1] is characterized by its moments, it seems natural to consider the following stochastic order: say that $\mu\le\mu'$ if $$\forall k\in\mathbb N,\qquad\int_0^1 x^k \mu(dx)\le \int_0^1 x^k \mu'(dx).$$ Has this notion been investigated? Is it equivalent to the (seemingly stronger) increasing convex order?

Comment: in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_dominance#Second-order  they go over at least the case of nondecreasing and concave utility functions

Comment: Probability measures on [0,1] are characterized by their moments, so we do get an order relation.

Comment: Sure, hence the title of my question. But what I am asking is whether this order is known, and equivalent to the classical increasing convex order.